# How does one exclude Mock or Stub structs from being built in Go

Tags: unit-testing, go

Assume for a moment I have a Go package with numerous interfaces. For this example, I'd focus on one called `Middleware` defined in `middleware.go`:

```
type Middleware interface {
  // some functions
}
```

I have some other parts of the system that uses it, so to better help test those parts of the system, I created a mock implementation by hand in `mock_middleware.go`:

```
type MockMiddleware struct {

}  

// implementations
```

When building the binary without tests, how do I exclude the mock classes from being built into the binary? I'm aware that `middleware_test.go` will be excluded, but I'd don't want to name all my mocks with that convention so as not to confuse actual tests with implementations to support testing.

Comment: AFAIK, Go's compiler eliminates dead code. So your mock types, if they are used only in tests, may already be excluded from the final binary. Also, possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/42827979/965900

Comment: That is a fair point. I'm wasting time compiling it, but for the size of my project isn't too much. I guess it will be an issue when your application becomes rather large (e.g. 100,000s of lines of code).

Answer (score 2):

One way could be to use [Build Constraints](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints).

Go even supports a built in `ignore` tag, but I'm not really sure of its interaction with the testing/benchmark toolchain:

> To keep a file from being considered for the build:
>
> // +build ignore

Comment: I looked at build constraints, but couldn't find documentation or examples that actually worked within this scenario.  Any suggestions on what to explore?

Comment: Sorry my only experience with them is for partitioning up a test suite and only executing tests with certain tags, ie unit, integration, service. Soundcloud illustrates how to do this here: http://peter.bourgon.org/go-in-production/#testing-and-validation