# Why are OCaml native binaries so large?

Tags: ocaml

I compiled a very simple, tiny OCaml program (which uses a few modules, among which Re2, if that's of any help for context) to a native binary, and the result executable was almost 15MB.

I also just tried compiling a simple Hello World, and the result binary was 347KB, which sounds like a lot for a line of code..

Why does this happen? Is there a more space-efficient way to compile OCaml, or are there some guidelines I should follow to minimize the size of the executable?

Comment: Possibly useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58028824/how-to-get-the-smallest-ocamlopt-compiled-native-binary

Comment: @Chris Looks like a complete answer, thanks :)